# Change image in expandable listview

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I would like to make some changes to my expandable list view. I have attached a before (what i currently have) and and proposed after picture but I have no idea how to achieve this so any help will be appreciated..

I would like to know  is...

a) How to change the list group icon dynamically? At the moment I an setting the current icon in the list_group.xml layout file using

```
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/app_leaguelogo"
```

Is there a way to do this when I'm adding the items to the array? Possibly pass the path?

b) In the list items, I'd somehow like to "split" each child item into 5 segments. So in the instance of the first list item in the after picture, I'd like

**Seg A** - Home team name (Central University)

**Seg B** - Logo for the home team

**Seg C** - Time

**Seg D** - Logo for away time

**Seg E** - Away team name (Days FC)

The general idea behind this is to be able to consistently space each item to avoid it being all over the place.

Here is the current **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: For a. , update your getGroupView in your adapter to add icon in your header. for b.  add another linear layout inside the existing one in your list_item with horizontal orientation. Now add : textview, imageview, textview , imageview and text view inside that linear layout. This gives you the layout for current content ( text, img, text, img, text). Populate these views accordingly in your getView.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, got it going!

One thing I can't get working is how to put items into the blocks for the logos, times and teams

At the moment in building an array  MatchArray.add("Central University 16:00 Days FC"); for example

Then I add it to a string list usingg listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),PSL);

How will i go about add a list of how teams, away times, logos etc?

Comment: Your adapter that is responsible for populating that content has the layout inflated while getting the view. So any view (EditText,ImageView etc) you define in this item layout, will be accessible in your getView just like you have access of views in OnCreate method of your layoutactivity. So you can set whatever you want here  ( like name, images etc) in appropriate view object, and will be displayed in your main layout.

Comment: I'm not following. I think i'm in the right place and I have this so far and it works when i use it to set the home team text, but I still don't understand how to add away team text? 



'public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
....
....
 txtHomeTeam.setText(childText);'

Comment: try following my suggestion marked in b in my first comment. You need multiple TextView and ImageView now since your content is not a single string anymore.